# Confusing instruction for a proof for showing that a diagram  has a limit from Arbib and Manes' text

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

The following are taken from $\textit{Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative}$ by Arbib and Manes

$\textbf{Theorem}$  Let $D$ be a diagram in $\textbf{K}$ with sets $V-$indexed family and every  $E-$indexed family of objects in $\textbf{K}$ has a product and if every pair of $\textbf{K-}$morphisms (between the same two objects) has an equalizer, $D$ has a limit.

Proof:  Form the $V-$indexed and $E-$indexed products shown below.  The universal property of the $E-$indexed product induces unique $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ as shown.

[image]

Let $h=eq(\psi_1, \psi_2)$.  Set $\gamma_i=\pi_i\circ h$ as shown above.  We claim that $(L,(\gamma_i))$ is a cone over $D$.  If $e:i\rightarrow j$ is in $E$, we must show

[image]

But

$$D_e\circ \gamma_i=D_e\circ pi_i\circ h=\bar{\pi}_e\circ\psi_2 \circ h=\bar{\pi}_e\circ \psi_1\circ h=\pi_j\circ h=\gamma_j.$$

Now suppose that $(L',(\gamma^{'}_i))$ is an arbitrary cone over $D$.  By the universal property of the $V-$indexed product, there exists unique $h'$ with $pi_i\circ h'=\gamma^{'}_i.$ (Look at $\textbf{(4)}$ imagining primes where necessary.)  Consulting $\textbf{(5)}$, substituting primes where necessary, we have

$$\bar{\pi}_e\circ\psi_1 \circ h'=\pi_j\circ h'=\gamma^{'}_j=D_e\circ \gamma^{'}_i=D_e\circ \pi_i\circ h'=\bar{\pi}_e\circ\psi_2 \circ h'.$$

As $e$ is arbitrary, $\psi_1 \circ h'=\psi_2 \circ h'$.  Since $h=eq(\psi_1, \psi_2)$ there exists unique $\Gamma:L'\rightarrow L$ such that $h\circ \Gamma=h'.$

[image]

Thus

$$h_i\circ\Gamma=\pi_i\circ h\circ \Gamma=\pi_i\circ h'=h^{'}_i.$$

If also $\bar{\Gamma}$ satisfies $h_i\circ \bar{\Gamma}=h^{'}_i$ then as $\pi_i\circ h\circ \bar{\Gamma}=\pi_i\circ h^{'}$ for all $i,$ $\bar{\Gamma}\circ h=h^{'}$ and so $\Gamma=\bar{\Gamma}.$

I just have a quick $\textbf{question}$   about the above proof:
when it says "Look at $\textbf{(4)}$ imagining primes where necessary.)  Consulting $\textbf{(5)}$, substituting primes where necessary..."  what did it mean by imagining primes where necessary", and then to ask the reader to consult $\textbf{(5)}$ for the purpose of substituting primes....?  What did the authors mean by that statement, I mean imagining primes and when is it necessary to make the necessary substitution?

Thank you in advance

Comment: One usually constructs limits and colimits first and then verifies that these indeed have the desired universal properties. However, while doing this one usually runs through the same argument twice. i.e. I construct something that has property A, then I assume that I have another thing with property A, now I need a unique morphism. And so the authors here just mean that the above diagrams and equalities for $\left(L,\gamma\right)$ also hold for the mirrored diagrams in $\left(L',\gamma'\right)$, and so they wanted to save some space and typing time. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Enkidu ah kk, thank you for clarifying that for me.